# Memory corruption when attempting to use strtok

Tags: c, strtok

When I run this code on my microcontroller, it crashes when attempting to printf on "price_right_of_period".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEBUG

char *str = "$3.45";

int main()
{
    char *decimal_pos; // where the decimal place is in the string
    char buffer[64]; // temporary working buffer
    
    int half_price_auto_calc = 1;
    
    // the cost of the product price difference for half price mode
    int price_save_left, price_save_right = 0;
    int price_half_left, price_half_right = 0;

    // EG: let's say we get the string "$2.89"
    char *price_left_of_period; // this will contain "2"
    char *price_right_of_period; // this will contain "89"
    
    // find where the decimal is
    decimal_pos = strstr(str, ".");
    
    if (decimal_pos != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe decimal point was found at array index %d\n", decimal_pos - str);
        printf("Splitting the string \"%s\" into left and right segments\n\n", str);
    }
    
    // get everything before the period
    strcpy(buffer, str); // copy the string
    
    price_left_of_period = strtok(buffer, ".");
    
    // if the dollar sign exists, skip over it
    if (price_left_of_period[0] == '$') price_left_of_period++;
    
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("price_left_of_period = \"%s\"\n", price_left_of_period);
    #endif
    
    // get everything after the period
    //
    // strtok remembers the last string it worked with and where it ended
    // to get the next string, call it again with NULL as the first argument
    price_right_of_period = strtok(NULL, "");
    
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("price_right_of_period = \"%s\"\n\n", price_right_of_period);
    #endif
    
    if (half_price_auto_calc == 1)
    {
        // calculate the amount we saved (before the decimal)
        price_save_left = atoi((const char *)price_left_of_period);

        // halve the value if half price value is true
        price_half_left = price_save_left / 2;
        
        // calculate the amount we saved (before the decimal)
        price_save_right = atoi((const char *)price_right_of_period);

        // halve the value if half price value is true
        price_half_right = price_save_right / 2;
        
        #ifdef DEBUG
            printf("price_half_left = \"%d\"\n", price_half_left);
            printf("price_half_right = \"%d\"", price_half_right);
        #endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code runs and works fine here: https://onlinegdb.com/kDAw2cJyz. However as mentioned above, on my MCU it crashes (image below).

[image: MCU printf crash]

Would anyone have any ideas why this might be happening as a result of my code? The code looks right to me but it's always nice to get a second opinion from other C experts :)

**SOLUTION:**

> Your code does have one bug. `%d\n", decimal_pos - str` doesn't work because `decimal_pos - str` has the wrong type to
> print through %d. You need to cast it (I doubt that's causing the
> crash but you can test by commenting it out and re-testing)

Comment: `price_right_of_period = strtok(NULL, "");` - what characters did you intend to use as token delimiters?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica He intended only the implicit token delimiter to be used -- the end of the string.

Comment: @UnholySheep Why wouldn't it be the rest of the parsed string? The end of the string is always implicitly a token delimiter and he didn't specify any additional delimiters.

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify any additional delimiters. It remembers the previous token.

Comment: @torxe:it remembers the rest of the string to be tolenised. That says nothing about the delimiters. Or for that matter the previous token.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't explain why it crashes on my microcontroller ;)

Comment: I wonder if your microcontroller's C library has a bug and crashes if no additional delimiters are specified. Can you test by passing `"."` as the delimiter list in the second call to `strtok`?

Comment: Ah, do you think it might actually be from `decimal_pos - str` in the `printf` I have?

Comment: By the way, your code does have one bug. `...  %d\n", decimal_pos - str)` doesn't work because `decimal_pos - str` has the wrong type to print through `%d`. You need to cast it. (I doubt that's causing the crash but you can test by commenting it out and re-testing.)

Comment: Yep! That's the problem. That's what's corrupting everything. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code indeed has a bug here:

```
printf("\nThe decimal point was found at array index %d\n", decimal_pos - str);
```

The difference of 2 pointers has type `ptrdiff_t` which may be different from `int` expected for `%d`. You should either use `%td` or cast the difference as `(int)(decimal_pos - str)`.  It is however very surprising that this type mismatch be the cause of your problem.

Note that you copy the string without testing its length in `strcpy(buffer, str);` which for this example is OK but might have undefined behavior if `str` points to a longer string.

The code is too complicated: there is no need for `strtok()` as you already have the offset to the decimal point if any. You can use `atoi()` with a pointer to the beginning of the integral portion without patching the `.` with a null byte. You could also use `strtol()` to avoid `strstr()` too.

Note also that the code will compute an incorrect price in most cases: `"$3.45"` will be changed to `"$1.22"` which is substantially more than a 50% rebate.

You should just convert the number as an integral number of cents and use that to compute the reduced price.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int half_price_auto_calc = 1;
char *str = "$3.45";

int main() {
    int cents;
    char *p = str;
    if (*p == '$')
        p++;
    // use strtol to convert dollars and cents
    cents = strtol(p, &p, 10) * 100;
    if (*p == '.') {
        cents += strtol(p + 1, NULL, 10);
    }
    if (half_price_auto_calc) {
        cents /= 2;
    }
    printf("reduced price: $%d.%02d\n", cents / 100, cents % 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I convert `cents` to a pointer though. `char *price_left_of_period`. `sprintf(price_left_of_period, "%d", cents / 100);` or `itoa(cents / 100, price_left_of_period, 10);` perhaps? Reason being is I have some functions later on in the program which require a pointer.

Comment: You should pass the destination array as a pair of argument `(char *dest, size_t size)` and construct the price into that with `snprintf(dest, size,  "$%d.%02d", cents / 100, cents % 100);`

Comment: The Arduino C library has no function called `snprintf`.

Comment: Thats too bad, use sprintf instead and remove the size argument

Comment: It doesn't work with `sprintf` either. When I try it on my microcontroller, it crashes (like my  screenshot in my original post where the `printf` goes crazy).

https://onlinegdb.com/5TMJt5Lm-

Comment: You modified the code. `price_left_of_period` and `price_right_of_period` should be defined as arrays: `char price_left_of_period[10], price_right_of_period[10];` and should change the second `sprintf` to `sprintf(price_right_of_period, "%02d", cents % 100);`

Comment: Ah, thanks. That solved it. I guess I can't use a pointer directly as I intended because it's not initialised prior to using it in `sprintf` and I have to use an array.